# Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()

Tags: java, scanner

Есть следующий код:

```
    String tmp="string";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        

    while (true) {
        //some code
        switch (sc.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                ...
            case 2:
                ...
            case 3:
                ...
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Введите критерий: ");
                tmp = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("tmp= " + tmp);
                break;                          
        }
```

Так вот после ввода 4 и соответственно перехода к **case 4:** мне не предлагается ввести строку, а просто записывается пустая строка в **tmp** и программа переходит на следующую итерацию. Читал про Scanner на разных сайтах, но так и не понял, в чем особенность его работы, из-за которой у меня возник данный казус. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавьте еще один `sc.nextLine();`  перед `tmp = sc.nextLine();`, чтоб было `System.out.print("Введите критерий: ");
                sc.nextLine();
                tmp = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("tmp= " + tmp);

                break;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ваша проблема задавалась и была решена на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods).

Когда вы вводите с клавиатуры число и жмёте на <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то <kbd>Enter</kbd> добавляет `\n` в конец. Проблема в том, что метод [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) не возвращает остаток строки `\n`, а считывает только число. Когда вы задаёте [`Scanner#nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), то он считывает этот самый остаток строки - `\n`, а следующий `nextLine()` уже считает уже именно следующую строку, которую вы хотите получить.

---

Решение заключается в добавлении ещё одного `nextLine()` после `nextInt()`:

```
    switch (sc.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
            ...
        case 2:
            ...
        case 3:
            ...
        case 4:
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите критерий: ");
            tmp = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("tmp = " + tmp);
            break;                          
    }
```