# Ввод в java c помощью Scanner

Tags: java, ввод

Никак не могу понять, что происходит:

```
int num; String s;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    num = sc.nextInt();
    s = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(s);
```

По моей логике сначала в переменную `num` должно записаться введенное `int` значение, затем в переменную `s` должно записаться введенное `string` значение. Но не тут то было. В `num` значение присваивается, а `s` просто пропускается и выводится уже просто пустая строка.
Если же поменять `num` и `s` местами, то все ок. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: После num = sc.nextInt(); добавьте sc.nextLine();

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/   и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/