# Ввод/вывод Java

Tags: java, input

```
System.out.println("number: ");
int a = in.nextInt();
//in.nextLine();
System.out.print("string: ");
String b = in.nextLine();
```

Без строчки кода в комментарии программа пропускает ввод строки b, если это строку раскомментить, то все работает. Почему?

Comment: Если вы проверите, что возвращает вызов `in.nextLine()`, который у вас закомментирован, то сразу поймёте ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: + [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526818/191482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут всё довольно просто. Нам запрашиваем написать число, мы вводим 1 и нажимаем enter. Получается строка "1\n" ("\n" появилась из - за того, что мы нажали enter).
 Из "1\n" командой in.nextInt() берётся '1'. Так "1\n" превращается в "\n". Затем in.nextLine() не начинает ждать, пока пользователь что - то введёт, так как ещё есть необработанные данный (та самая "\n", которая осталась от "1\n"). Он берёт из оставшейся строки "\n" **всё**, что находится до символа '\n'. В нашем случае до '\n' ничего не находится, и in.nextLine() возвращает "".
Если раскомментировать in.nextLine(), то из буфера будет убрана мешающая "\n" и при следующем вызове in.nextLine() система будет ожидать ввода пользователя, так как вся информация обработана и её in буфер чист.

Comment: Бонус: "лишнего" in.nextLine() можно избежать, если вместо in.nextInt() использовать in.nextLine(), кастанув его в int.

Comment: В чем смысл ответа на явный дубликат, который указан уже в комментариях и вопрос будет закрыт одним из них? О_о