# Не могу ввести сначала число, потом строку

Tags: java, клавиатура

Код программы еще не закончен, но это часть заключается в переводе строки в массив. В строке вводим числа через пробел. Проблема в том, что если сначала вводим строку, потом число, то работает, а тут нет, и выдает ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Как я понял, это ошибка говорит о том, что я не ввел строку. Но я не могу ее ввести, почему то.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt();
        String str1 = in.nextLine();
        String strArr1[] = str1.split(" ");
        int numArr1[] = new int[strArr1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr1.length; i++) numArr1[i] = 
Integer.parseInt(strArr1[i]);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr1));
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем в коде переменная `x` и ее вывод? Если убрать `x` то все будет правильно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1025 . Решаю эту задачу. Я еще не написал преобразования. Хотел сначала проверить перевод строки в массив.

Comment: Разобрался, ответ нашел тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-nextint

Comment: Ответ на вопрос сам нашел тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 0):

Например мы ввели строку `1 2 3 4 5`. По вашему коду считывается первое число 1 и остается число строка `2 3 4 5`. После того, как вы делаете `split(" ")`, то получается массив `String[] array = {"", "2", "3", "4", "5"}`. И когда вы начинаете, считывать парсить массив, то пустую строку распарсить не получается, нужно убрать `in.nextInt()`.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String str1 = in.nextLine();
String strArr1[] = str1.split(" ");
int numArr1[] = new int[strArr1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strArr1.length; i++)
    numArr1[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr1[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr1));
```

Comment: Не, я же хочу ввести число, потом нажать Enter, и потом ввести строку. Он же должен нормально работать при этом

Comment: Когда вы пишете in.netInt(), то оно не переходит на новую линию, а остается на старой и следующий in.nextLine() берет все остальное после числа. то есть пустую строку. Если вы уж так хотите использовать nextInt, то вот так возможно решить эту проблему:

        int x = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        String str = in.nextLine();