# Не отрабатывает Scanner во второй раз

Tags: java, scanner

Есть метод добавления товара в корзину, когда вызываю его в первый раз, всё отрабатывает корректно, когда вызываю второй раз в product ничего не записывается, при вызове в третий раз, всё снова отрабатывается корректно.

```
public void addProduct() {
    String product;
    int quantity;
    System.out.print("Пожалуйста, введите наименование товара: ");
    product = scan.nextLine();
    for (Product p : Products) {
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getName())) {
            System.out.print("Пожалуйста, введите количество нужного товара: ");
            quantity = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Товар: " + product + ", в количестве: " + quantity + " шт. был успешно добавлен в корзину!");
            choose = product + " " + quantity;
            Goods.add(choose);
            sum += p.getCost() * quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Может кто поможет понять, почему не хочет сканировать во второй раз?

Comment: Еще один похожий вопрос: [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt() \[дубликат\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextInt() забирает из введённой строки только число, но оставляет \n - символ переноса строки, который получается, когда пользователь нажимает Enter. Затем при вызове метода nextLine() он читает этот оставшийся символ и сразу заканчивает работу. 
Проблему легко можно решить добавив вызов nextLine(), после вызова nextInt(). Он будет читать этот символ. Зато следующий nextLine() отработает как надо.

```
public void addProduct() {
    String product;
    int quantity;
    System.out.print("Пожалуйста, введите наименование товара: ");
    product = scan.nextLine();
    for (Product p : Products) {
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getName())) {
            System.out.print("Пожалуйста, введите количество нужного товара: ");
            quantity = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();     //fix!
            System.out.println("Товар: " + product + ", в количестве: " + quantity + " шт. был успешно добавлен в корзину!");
            choose = product + " " + quantity;
            Goods.add(choose);
            sum += p.getCost() * quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот рабочий код. И ссылка на такой же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo?rq=1) на англоязычном stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо, scan.nextLine(); и правда помог, единственное что - хотел бы узнать, почему при его вызове сразу принимает /n, а не дает возможность еще что нибудь ввести, а когда я присваиваю второй раз к product (без scan.nextLine()), он дает еще что нибудь ввести после /n?

Comment: /n - просто осталось введенным значением,а nextLine() работает так, что читает введенные значения и при нахождении /n (обычно это нажатие Enter пользователем, а не остаток переноса строки от прошлой строки) сразу заканчивает работу и возвращает прочитанную строку.

Answer (score 0):

```
Сделайте примерно так...
```

Классы Product  и Basket  написал, а класс Main попробуйте отрефакторить сами

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product ("aaa", 3));
        productList.add(new Product ("bbb", 2));
        productList.add(new Product ("ccc", 4));

        Basket basket = new Basket();

        addProduct(basket, productList);
        addProduct(basket, productList);
        addProduct(basket, productList);

        System.out.println(basket.get());
        System.out.println(basket.getTotalCost());

    }

    public static boolean addProduct(Basket basket, List<Product> products) {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Пожалуйста, введите наименование товара: ");
            String choose = scan.nextLine();
            for (Product product : products) {
                if (product.getName().equals(choose)) {
                    System.out.println("Пожалуйста, введите количество нужного товара: ");
                    int quantity = basket.add(product, scan.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Товар: " + product + ", в количестве: " + quantity + " шт. был успешно добавлен в корзину!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Товар не найден!");            
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при вводе количества товара!");
        }
        return false;
    }

}


class Product implements Comparable<Product>{
    private final String name;
    private final int cost;

    public Product(String name, int cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 73 * hash + this.cost;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (this.cost != other.cost) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "name=" + name + ", cost=" + cost + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product p) {
        return (p==null) ? -1 : this.getName().compareTo(p.getName());
    }

}

class Basket {

    private final Map<Product, Integer> basketMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public int add(Product choose, int quantity){
        if (!basketMap.containsKey(choose)) basketMap.put(choose, quantity);
        else basketMap.put(choose, basketMap.get(choose) + quantity);
        return quantity;
    }

    public Map<Product, Integer> get(){
        return basketMap;
    }

    public int getTotalCost(){
        return basketMap.entrySet().stream()
                .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey().getCost()*e.getValue())
                .sum();
    }

}
```