# Неверно работает nextLine()

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt(), c = 0;
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Tetrahedron", 4);
        map.put("Cube", 6);
        map.put("Octahedron", 8);
        map.put("Dodecahedron", 12);
        map.put("Icosahedron", 20);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            c += map.get(scan.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Есть простая программа, считывающая количество граней введенных многоугольников, но она вылетает при попытке получить какое-либо значение из `HashMap`.

Comment: Дубликат [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526818/199253)  и даже еще один [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499681/199253) Вообще их уже туча)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-nextint)

Answer (score 1):

Сама проблема заключается в том, что `scan.nextInt()` считывает не всю строку, а лишь число, оставляя в буфере `\n`, который и принимает следующий `scan.nextLine()`. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно, например вызвать холостой `scan.nextLine()` перед основным рабочим телом Вашей программы. Это уберет из буфера перенос строки и далее все заработает так, как того бы хотелось.