# java.util.Scanner, hasNext...(); & next...(); Работа с памятью объекта

Tags: java, scanner

Что происходит?! Как работают методы класса Scanner next...(); и hasNext...(); с памятью?

Пример:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean b = console.hasNextLine();
        String i = console.nextLine();
        String str = console.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Output:");
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.println("str = " + str);
    }
}
```

При инициализации переменной b будет запущен ввод с консоли. Однако уже при инициализации переменной i он не потребуется. Метод nextInt(); почему-то просто берёт то же значение, что вводилось чуть раньше при вызове метода hasNextLine(); А вот уже при инициализации переменной str просит ввести новую строку.

Далее веселее:
Меняем тип переменной i со String на int.
При инициализации переменной b активируется ввод с консоли. Этот же ввод перенаправляется в метод nextInt(); при инициализации переменной i. А инициализация переменной str вообще пропускается! Не просят ввести очередную строку.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean b = console.hasNextLine();
        int i = console.nextInt();
        String str = console.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Output:");
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.println("str = " + str);
    }
}
```

Очевидно это связано с тем, как работают эти методы с памятью объекта типа Scanner, в данном случае "console". Но где все эти фишки и случаи расписаны подробно - не знаю. Как и то, что вообще происходит во втором случае?!
Пожалуйста, помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Первый пример

```
    boolean b = console.hasNextLine();
```

Как программе определить будет ли введена следующая строка? Никак. Входной файл может быть закрыт в любой момент. Поэтому программа ждёт ввода каких-нибудь данных.

Входной поток с консоли буферизуется по строкам. Вы заметили что строку можно редактировать и программа не видит ваших действий пока вы не нажмёте `Enter`?

Сочетание этих двух факторов заставляет программу ждать пока вы введёте первую строку.

```
    String i = console.nextLine();
```

Когда исполняется этот код, строка уже введена и доступна программе. Переменная `i` немедленно заполняется значением и мы движемся дальше.

```
    String str = console.nextLine();
```

А следующую строку пользователь ещё не вводил. Программа останавливается и ждёт пока вы отредактируете текст и нажмёте `Enter`. После этого двигаемся дальше.

### Второй пример

```
    boolean b = console.hasNextLine();
```

Тут всё тоже самое что и в примере выше.

```
    int i = console.nextInt();
```

Здесь строка уже считана, начинаем её разбирать: пропускаем пробелы, считываем знак числа и цифры и останавливаемся на первом  [пробельном символе](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#default-delimiter). Это может быть перевод строки, пробел или табуляция, но не только.

Число считывается из входного потока посимвольно. Когда найден неподходящий символ его "возвращают" в поток, так что когда вы продолжите чтение, первым вы увидите его.

Так или иначе перевод строки после чтения целого числа останется в потоке.

```
    String str = console.nextLine();
```

Читаем следующую строку. Но нет, не следующую: читаем остаток текущей строки. Если вы нажали `Enter` сразу после числа, вы получите пустую строку.

### Вывод

Видно что `nextInt` и `nextLine` как-то плохо работают друг с другом. Это объяснимо: `nextInt` устроен так чтобы не отличать пробелы от переводов строк. `nextLine` - наоборот.

Решить проблему можно радикально: всегда читать целые строки. Если вам нужна не строка а целое, то извлекать его из строки после чтения:

```
String line = console.nextLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(line, 10);
```

Вся механика хорошо описана в [официальной документации по Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Опущены детали относящиеся к буферизации: операционная система пересылает ввод целыми строками и т.п..

Comment: Уважаемый Станислав, а почему же последовательность команд:  int a = console.nextInt();                
int b = console.nextInt();  Работает как и предполагается. Т. е. запрашивает 2 ввода с консоли. А вот если:  int a = console.nextInt();  String b = console.nextLine();  То уже происходит описанная вами выше ситуация. Ну и как собственно тогда добиться, что бы когда я вызывал метод .nextLine(); после метода nextInt(); он именно запрашивал очередной ввод с консоли, а не считывал пустую строку? А главное, если сначала вызвать .nextLine();, а потом .nextInt();, то всё ОК. В чём же фишка?

Comment: Вам показалось: введите два целых числа через пробел и программа не будет ждать перевода строки. Если вы хотите вводить всегда одно целое число на строке, то всегда вызывайте `nextLine` после `nextInt`.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Думаю это что вам нужно, что вводить данные с консоли построчно.

Comment: Теперь более менее понятно. Спасибо большое. Т. е. нельзя рассчитывать на повторный запрос ввода с консоли методом .nextLine(); после вызова метода nextInt(); ? И главное, на каком ресурсе эти нюансы расписаны, если вам известно? В документации Oracle такие фишки не описываются.

Comment: Java вводит данные следуя образцу заданному C/C++. А он в свою очередь взят из POSIX. Если у вас есть опыт в C/C++ и POSIX,  то вы знаете чего ждать от ввода. Как я понимаю вы на ты с отладчиком. Тогда берите [исходный код](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java) и смотрите как он работает. В принципе всё тоже самое можно вычитать в документации по `Scanner`.

Comment: Станислав, ещё раз спасибо за информацию. А для читающих этот вопрос и ответы к нему. Вот аналогичная проблема на Stack'e.(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-не-считывает-строку-после-nextint). Туда тоже загляните.

Comment: Станислав, ещё раз здравствуйте. Ни в коем случае не хочу капать на мозги, но выше вы писали что метод nextInt(); считывает строку пропуская начальные пробелы (так и есть), далее посимвольно до первого символа-не-цифры: пробел, символ перевода строки или любой другой. Так вот если методу nextInt(); на вход подать, условно, 123str  то, дойдя до буквы s, JVM выдаст ошибку и прервёт исполнение; а не считает 123 и не передаст str в последующие методы. Я бы вставил блок кода для проверки, но этот Markdown - просто ужас. Код пастится одной строкой с разрывами вместо блока кода. :(

Comment: Всё в порядке. Я поправил ошибки: теперь только пробельные символы. Спасибо!