# Компилятор выдает NumberFormatException в цикле do -while

Tags: java

подскажи пожалуйста. почему у меня вылазит NumberFormatException после окончания расчета и при вводе yes. Я же закинул `mathExpression = sc.nextLine()`  в do - while. Получается, что компилятор идет сначала на строку создания объекта с пустым параметром. Где ошибка?
Помогите написать цикл, чтобы при пустом параметре объекта Calculator calc вызывалась фраза "Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел:" и метод  `mathExpression = sc.nextLine();`

```
    class CalculatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mathExpression;
        String userAnswer = "yes";
        while (userAnswer.equals("yes")) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел: ");
                mathExpression = sc.nextLine();
            } while (mathExpression.equals(" "));
            Calculator calc = new Calculator(mathExpression);
            System.out.println(calc.calculate());
            do {
                System.out.print("Do you want to continue? [yes/no]: ");
                userAnswer = sc.next();
            } while (!userAnswer.equals("yes") && !userAnswer.equals("no"));
        }
    }

}


 Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел: 
6 * 9
54
Do you want to continue? [yes/no]: y
Do you want to continue? [yes/no]: yes
Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:24)
    at com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest.main(CalculatorTest.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

В классе калькулятор конструктор

```
public Calculator(String mathExpression) {
        String[] arrExpression = mathExpression.split(" ");
        firstNumb = Integer.parseInt(arrExpression[0]);
        sign = arrExpression[1].charAt(0);
        secondNumb = Integer.parseInt(arrExpression[2]);
    }
```

Далее производятся математические действия с примитивами из массива arrExpression

```
public int calculate() {
        switch (sign) {
            case '+':
                return Math.addExact(firstNumb, secondNumb);
            case '-':
                return firstNumb - secondNumb;
            case '*':
                return firstNumb * secondNumb;
            case '/':
                return firstNumb / secondNumb;
            case '^':
                return (int) Math.pow(firstNumb, secondNumb);
            case '%':
                return (firstNumb % secondNumb);
            default:
                System.out.println("Введи знак мат.операции " + " + " + " - " + " * " + " / " + " ^ " + " % ");
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Что в классе `Calculator`?

Comment: Я добавил код из класса Calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сделайте

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mathExpression;
    String userAnswer = "yes";
    while (userAnswer.equals("yes")) {
      do {
        System.out.println("Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел: ");
        mathExpression = sc.nextLine();
      } while (mathExpression.equals(" "));
      Calculator calc = new Calculator(mathExpression);
      System.out.println(calc.calculate());
      do {
        System.out.print("Do you want to continue? [yes/no]: ");
        userAnswer = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
      } while (!userAnswer.equals("yes") && !userAnswer.equals("no"));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сделать так:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mathExpression;
        String userAnswer = "yes";
        while (userAnswer.equals("yes")) {
            mathExpression = "";
            userAnswer = "yes";
            System.out.println("Введите  выражение по типу a + b через пробел: ");
            do { 
                mathExpression = sc.nextLine();
            }while (mathExpression.equals(""));
            try {
                System.out.println(Calculator.calculate(mathExpression));
                do {
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? [yes/no]: ");
                    userAnswer = sc.next();
                } while (!userAnswer.equals("yes") && !userAnswer.equals("no"));
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException | StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println("Неправильный формат");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

```
public class Calculator {

    public static int calculate(String mathExpression) {
        String[] arrExpression = mathExpression.split(" ");
        int firstNumb = Integer.parseInt(arrExpression[0]);
        char sign = arrExpression[1].charAt(0);
        int secondNumb = Integer.parseInt(arrExpression[2]);
        switch (sign) {
        case '+':
            return Math.addExact(firstNumb, secondNumb);
        case '-':
            return firstNumb - secondNumb;
        case '*':
            return firstNumb * secondNumb;
        case '/':
            return firstNumb / secondNumb;
        case '^':
            return (int) Math.pow(firstNumb, secondNumb);
        case '%':
            return (firstNumb % secondNumb);
        default:
            System.out.println("Введи знак мат.операции " + " + " + " - " + " * " + " / " + " ^ " + " % ");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Теперь вместо ошибки будет выскакивать красная надпись "Неправильный формат", а код будет продолжать работать

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ на вопрос нашел здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-не-считывает-строку-после-nextint/ . Оказалось, что это специфика Scanner.

Comment: Я изменил на вариант со `static`, это вариант гораздо проще (кода меньше)