# Не могу понять причину остановки программы

Tags: java

Программа останавливается после вывода данной строки:

```
    System.out.println("----------------------Такого файла не существует! Создать? (Введите Да или Нет)");
```

Сам код:

```
    if(f.exists() == false)
            {
                System.out.println("----------------------Такого файла не существует! Создать? (Введите Да или Нет)");
                String Variable = scanner.nextLine();
                Variable = Variable.toLowerCase();
                if(Variable.equals("да"))
                {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
                    
                    String text = "";
                    System.out.println("Введите данные для записи в файл: ");
                    text = scanner.next();
                    writer.write(text);
                    writer.close();
                }
```

В чем заключается проблема в остановке программы?

Comment: Ожидает ввода ваша программа

Comment: Прям сосем останавливается и выходит из неё? Может быть она всё же ждёт ввода данных?

Comment: Введите да и нажмите enter

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку нашел. Надо было написать scanner.next(), а не scanner.nextLine(). Но теперь возникла другая ошибка. Программа останавливается когда доходит до if. В чем теперь ошибка? :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526914/191482, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499688/191482, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nextLine

Comment: может`if`не выполняется например Вы получайте `да\n`, проверьте длину строки:
`System.out.println(Variable.length);` и еще проверьте условие: `System.out.println(Variable.equals("да"))`

Comment: @Agzam4 нет. там проблема в next и nextLine. инфа 100%

Comment: В первом сообщении у вас 'да' с большой буквы, а в условии с маленькой. Если хотите, можете использовать метод equalsIgnoreCase()