# Почему не выполняется switch?

Tags: java

Коллеги, добрый день, написал небольшой калькулятор, и мне нужно, чтоб Switch выполнялся в зависимости от того, какому тексту равна переменная action, но после комплияции консоль запрашивает 1-е число, 2-е число, и спрашивает чему будет равна переменная action, но не даёт ввести значение, а сразу заканчивает выполнение кода. Ниже прилагаю код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switchcase {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 1 число: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 2 число: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Какое действие хотите совершить?: ");
    String action = scan.nextLine();

    switch (action) {

        case "+":
            System.out.println("Результат - " + (num1 + num2) );
            break;
        case "-":
            System.out.println("Результат - " + (num1 - num2) );
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println("Результат - " + (num1 * num2) );
        break;
        case "/":
            if (num2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Введите число отличное от нуля.");
            }
            System.out.println("Результат - " + (num1 / num2) );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

В видеоуроке, по которому я обучаюсь, автор говорит, что в int num2 есть какой то скрытый символ, и он подставляется в String action, что это за символ, и что это за прикол?

```
int num2 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.print("Какое действие хотите совершить?: ");
String action = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: _nextLine() читает до конца текущей строки (символа перевода строки или конца потока) и возвращает всё, что было в этой строке. nextInt() извлекает число и оставляет "\n" в буфере. nextLine() натыкается на \n и прекращает работу, прочитав 0 символов — пустую строку. Можно вызвать nextLine() дважды, чтобы поглотить этот перенос строки и ожидать новой строки_ https://qna.habr.com/q/269359

Comment: А почему nextInt() вводит \n в конце, а nextLine() этого не делает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-nextint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы вводите int num2 вы на клаиватуре нажимаете число и потом клавишу Enter. Клавиша Enter передает сканеру знак \n - перенос строки. И именно это значение записывается в вашу переменную action. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно "съесть" лишний символ перевода строки. Делается это вот так:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 1 число: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 2 число: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); // СЪЕСТЬ ЛИШНИЙ ЗНАК ПЕРЕНОСА СТРОКИ!!!!
    System.out.print("Какое действие хотите совершить?: ");
    String action = scan.nextLine();
```

Попробуйте так, и все заработает

Comment: А почему в первом nextInt() \n автоматически не передаётся, а в последнем nextInt() передаётся?

Comment: Передается также. Получается следующая картина. Вы при первом int передаете число и знак переноса. И дальше снова пользуетесь методом nextInt() - он проигнорирует знак переноса, его интересует только число. Вы снова передаете число и знак переноса строки. А дальше вы уже используете метод не nextInt(), а nextLine() - а тут уже другое дело. Он знак переноса не проигнорирует, а запишет в вашу переменную

Comment: Это особенность Java? Почему так?

Comment: Это особенность сканера. Он читает строку до конца. И если вконце строки стоит символ перевода строки, то он также будет включен в то, что вычитал сканер.

Comment: А всё же, он же в ту же строку передает, а не в следующую свой \n, как тогда его следующая строка считывает?

Comment: Чтобы сориентироваться можно представить так: вы передаете в сканер "26 \n". nextInt() забирает себе 26, а \n "остается в сканере. В следующий раз вы передаете "48 \n". nextInt() забирает себе 48, а \n остается в сканере. Потом вы вызываете nextLine(), а в сканере уже висит \n с прошлого раза. И nextLine() забирает себе этот самый \n. Это если упростить

Comment: Да, я понял Вас, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Также решением вопроса является использование метода scan.next(); заместо scan.nextLine()